# Typecheck createAction Redux helper

Tags: typescript, redux, union, flux

I have `Action` type defined like this:

```
type Action =
    { type: 'DO_X' }
    |
    { type: 'DO_Y', payload: string }
    |
    { type: 'DO_Z', payload: number }
```

It's a union type where each member is a valid action.

Now I'd like to create a function `createAction` that accepts `type` and returns a new function that accepts `payload`.

```
const doZ = createAction('DO_Z')
console.log(doZ(42)) // { type: 'DO_Z', payload: 42 }
```

Here's my current implementation:

```
const createAction = (type: Action['type']) =>
  (payload?: any) =>
    ({ type, payload })
```

It typechecks `type` like I want to. How can I also typecheck `payload`? I want `payload` to match type of correct action based on `type`. For example, `doZ` should fail when called with a `string` because it's `payload` says that it accepts only `number`.

Comment: Have you tried a definition like `<Type, Payload>(type: Type) : (payload: Payload) => {type: Type, payload: Payload}` ?

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin That doesn't seem to work. Type is being used as value. But generics seems to be a step in the right direction. How does TypeScript know that `Type` and `Payload` is coming from `Action`?

Comment: Ho you are on Typescript... I haven't checked the tags. I don't actually know, I'm using Flow for typing !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical answer to this question depends on your exact use case.  I'm going to assume that you need `Action` to evaluate exactly to the type you wrote; that is, an object of `type: "DO_X"` does *not* have a `payload` property of any kind.  This implies that `createAction("DO_X")` should be a function of zero arguments, while `createAction("DO_Y")` should be a function of a single `string` argument.  I'm also going to assume that you want any type parameters on `createAction()` to be automatically inferred, so that you don't, for example, need to specify `createAction<Blah>("DO_Z")` for any value of `Blah`.  If either of these restrictions is lifted, you can simplify the solution to something like the one given by @Arnavion.

---

TypeScript doesn't like mapping types from property *values*, but it's happy to do so from property *keys*.  So let's build the `Action` type in a way that provides us with types the compiler can use to help us.  First we describe the payloads for each action type like this:

```
type ActionPayloads = {
  DO_Y: string;
  DO_Z: number;
}
```

Let's also introduce any `Action` types without a payload:

```
type PayloadlessActionTypes = "DO_X" | "DO_W";
```

(I've added a `'DO_W'` type just to show how it works, but you can remove it).

Now we're finally able to express `Action`:

```
type ActionMap = {[K in keyof ActionPayloads]: { type: K; payload: ActionPayloads[K] }} & {[K in PayloadlessActionTypes]: { type: K }};
type Action = ActionMap[keyof ActionMap];
```

The `ActionMap` type is an object whose keys are the `type` of each `Action`, and whose values are the corresponding elements of the `Action` union.  It is the intersection of the `Action`s with `payload`s, and the `Action` without `payload`s.  And `Action` is just the value type of `ActionMap`.   Verify that `Action` is what you expect.

We can use `ActionMap` to help us with typing the `createAction()` function.  Here it is:

```
function createAction<T extends PayloadlessActionTypes>(type: T): () => ActionMap[T];
function createAction<T extends keyof ActionPayloads>(type: T): (payload: ActionPayloads[T]) => ActionMap[T];
function createAction(type: string) {
  return (payload?: any) => (typeof payload === 'undefined' ? { type } : { type, payload });
}
```

It's an overloaded function with a type parameter `T` corresponding to the `type` of `Action` you are creating.  The top two declarations describe the two cases:  If `T` is the `type` of an `Action` with no `payload`, the return type is a zero-argument function returning the right type of `Action`.  Otherwise, it's a one-argument function that takes the right type of `payload` and returns the right type of `Action`.  The implementation (the third signature and body) is similar to yours, except that it doesn't add `payload` to the result if there is no `payload` passed in.

---

All done!  We can see that it works as desired:

```
var x = createAction("DO_X")(); // x: { type: "DO_X"; }
var y = createAction("DO_Y")("foo"); // y: { type: "DO_Y"; payload: string; }
var z = createAction("DO_Z")(5); // z: { type: "DO_Z"; payload: number; }

createAction("DO_X")('foo'); // too many arguments
createAction("DO_X")(undefined); // still too many arguments
createAction("DO_Y")(5); // 5 is not a string
createAction("DO_Z")(); // too few arguments
createAction("DO_Z")(5, 5); // too many arguments
```

You can see all this in action [on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ActionPayloads%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20DO_Y%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20DO_Z%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20PayloadlessActionTypes%20%3D%20%27DO_X%27%20%7C%20%27DO_W%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ActionMap%20%3D%20%7B%5BK%20in%20keyof%20ActionPayloads%5D%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20K%3B%20payload%3A%20ActionPayloads%5BK%5D%20%7D%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BK%20in%20PayloadlessActionTypes%5D%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20K%20%7D%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Action%20%3D%20ActionMap%5Bkeyof%20ActionMap%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createAction%3CT%20extends%20PayloadlessActionTypes%3E%28type%3A%20T%29%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20ActionMap%5BT%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createAction%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20ActionPayloads%3E%28type%3A%20T%29%3A%20%28payload%3A%20ActionPayloads%5BT%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20ActionMap%5BT%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createAction%28type%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%28payload%3F%3A%20any%29%20%3D%3E%20%28typeof%20payload%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27undefined%27%20%3F%20%7B%20type%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%20type%2C%20payload%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20createAction%28%22DO_X%22%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20x%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22DO_X%22%3B%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20createAction%28%22DO_Y%22%29%28%22foo%22%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20y%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22DO_Y%22%3B%20payload%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20z%20%3D%20createAction%28%22DO_Z%22%29%285%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20z%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22DO_Z%22%3B%20payload%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateAction%28%22DO_X%22%29%28%27foo%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20too%20many%20arguments%0D%0AcreateAction%28%22DO_X%22%29%28undefined%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20still%20too%20many%20arguments%0D%0AcreateAction%28%22DO_Y%22%29%285%29%3B%20%2F%2F%205%20is%20not%20a%20string%0D%0AcreateAction%28%22DO_Z%22%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20too%20few%20arguments%0D%0AcreateAction%28%22DO_Z%22%29%285%2C%205%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20too%20many%20arguments).  Hope it works for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Verbose but this works:

```
type XAction = { type: 'DO_X', payload: undefined }; 
type YAction = { type: 'DO_Y', payload: string }; 
type ZAction = { type: 'DO_Z', payload: number }; 

type Action = XAction | YAction | ZAction;

const createAction = <T extends Action>(type: T['type']) =>
    (payload: T['payload']) =>
        ({ type, payload });

// Do compile:

createAction<XAction>("DO_X")(undefined);
createAction<YAction>("DO_Y")("foo");
createAction<ZAction>("DO_Z")(5);

// Don't compile:

createAction<XAction>("DO_X")(5); // Expected `undefined`, got number
createAction<YAction>("DO_Y")(5); // Expected string, got number
createAction<ZAction>("DO_X")(5); // Expected `"DO_Z"`, got `"DO_X"`
```

---

The easier way (not forcing the type parameter of `createAction`):

```
type Action = { type: 'DO_X', payload: undefined } | { type: 'DO_Y', payload: string } | { type: 'DO_Z', payload: number };

createAction("DO_Y")("foo");
```

unfortunately allows `createAction<YAction>("DO_Y")(5)` etc to compile, since `T` is always inferred as `Action` and thus the `payload` parameter is `string|number|undefined`